# How to enable CUDA for Huggingface Trainer on Windows?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use the Trainer from the transformers library from HuggingFace in Python:

```
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainingArguments
from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainer

#  ...

training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(fp16=True,

# ...

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer( args=training_args,

# ...
```

I get this error message:

> ValueError: FP16 Mixed precision training with AMP or APEX (`--fp16`)
> and FP16 half precision evaluation (`--fp16_full_eval`) can only be
> used on CUDA or NPU devices or certain XPU devices (with IPEX).

It seems like I am missing some CUDA installation, but I can't figure out, what exactly I need. I tried (without success):

```
py -m pip install --upgrade setuptools pip wheel
py -m pip install nvidia-pyindex
py -m pip install nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12

py -m pip install nvidia-nvml-dev-cu12
py -m pip install nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12
```

System info:

- Windows 11 Build 22621
- Python 3.11.7, running inside a venv
- Geforce RTX 4070

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Did you install the [CUDA toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)? Normally the `nvidia-smi` command is good to see if it works, your driver and CUDA versions are listed there as well.

Comment: I installed the toolkit now, but it didn't change anything. Still the same error message. nvidia-smi reports "NVIDIA-SMI 536.67 | Driver Version 546.33 | CUDA Version 12.3 | GPU 0 = NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. Adding this line to the code

```
model.to('cuda')
```

gave a more meaningful error message:

> Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Created the correct pip install command here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
(something like `pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121` )
and it worked.